# How to clear the content in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel i have Multiple rows of values more than 5000 unique

I want to clear the content of the table Name by keeping only one record

Would you please help me in getting this sorted in excel

Please refer the image [image: JbeVl.jpg]

Comment: do you want to do this in place?  As is the actually expected is that column A would change from what it is to what you want as shown in column D.

Comment: "Multiple rows of values more than 5000 unique " <-- is the data sorted?

Comment: Then the next question, Is it okay to make the characters white so they are invisible, but the data is still there, just not seen?

Comment: You could pivot your data to get the same effect